# Why does Keras (tf) Binary Classification predict() always gives extreme probabilities, either zero or one?

Tags: algorithm, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying implement a NN model (wide and deep learning) with tf.keras v2.0 to do some binary classification. I have ~50k training samples and ~10k testing samples. The class distribution is fairly even (see image below). 
My training and testing accuracy varies between 0.6-0.7 depending on my hyper parameters. Precision and Recall are both around 0.7 as well for testing.

My NN's last layer is a 2-unit Softmax and I'm using `categorical_crossentropy` as my loss function.

After training, I try to get the probabilities for each prediction using `model.predict()`, but the results for each probability is almost always `[0., 1.]` or `[1., 0.]`. I'm wondering why does this happen?

[image]
[image]
[image]

I've tried using a 1-unit Sigmoid + `binary_classification` or even train for 1 epoch, the results have been the same.

Here's the simplified structure of the NN:

Deep component is being fed with Embeddings of continuous features, then passes through 3 feed-forward layers with Dropouts in between.

Wide component is a one layer logistic regression that's being fed with cross product features of categorical data.

```
out_layer = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([deep_component_outlayer, logistic_input])
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')(out_layer)
```

Comment: Have you tried adding weight decay?

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat Yes I have, but it did not help. I think the problem lies with my dataset. I will update if anything,  thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you get the same result using `model.predict_proba(...)`?

Comment: @cddt That method doesn't exist anymore AFAIK, at least for functional APIs, but it's the same as model.predict() according to https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/sequential.py#L231